# How to pass %r from format time MySQL query to Python Code?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to give a different format to date time in MySQL to insert that query in a Python Code but i get an error near to the time_format MySQL function. How can i solve this error? I'm using %r to change time in 12 hour AM or PM format (hh:mm:ss AM/PM) instead 24 hour time format.

I've tried adding " and ' but i get the same error.

```
sql2 = "SELECT A.DescripcionProducto,A.TipoUnidad,A.ExistenciaProducto,MAX(Concat(DATE_FORMAT(FechaSalida, "%d-%m-%Y"),' ',time_format(FechaSalida,"%r"))) FROM newdb.inventario A LEFT JOIN newdb.inventariodetalle B ON A.IdProducto = B.IdProducto where DescripcionProducto = %s GROUP BY A.IdProducto"
```

I expect this kind of result: '25-06-2019 07:42:09 PM' but it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up single and double quotes.

```
sql2 = 'SELECT A.DescripcionProducto,A.TipoUnidad,A.ExistenciaProducto,MAX(Concat(DATE_FORMAT(FechaSalida, "%d-%m-%Y")," ",time_format(FechaSalida,"%r"))) FROM newdb.inventario A LEFT JOIN newdb.inventariodetalle B ON A.IdProducto = B.IdProducto where DescripcionProducto = %s GROUP BY A.IdProducto'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, i've tried as you said but i get the same error message: TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str. %d is for DATE_FORMAT MySQL Function just like %r for TIME_FORMAT, both are recognized for the intepreter like a Python component not like a MySQL Function.